# How to add link to Revolution Slider button?

Tags: html, revolution-slider

I purchased an HTML theme, while editing it there is some Revolution Slider code.

I have the following for now - This makes the text inside the button i.e. Get Started into a link. I can't figure out how to make full button into a clickable link.

```
<rs-layer id="slider-1-slide-1-layer-1" class="rev-btn" 
data-type="button" data-color="#251117" data-rsp_ch="on" 
data-xy="x:l,l,c,c;xo:92px,92px,0,92px;y:m;yo:150px,95px,150px,97px;" 
data-text="w:normal;s:17;l:60;fw:700;" data-dim="minh:0px,0px,none,0px;" 
data-padding="r:40;l:40;" data-border="bor:4px,4px,4px,4px;" 
data-frame_0="x:50,50,31,31;" 
data-frame_1="st:150;sp:1000;sR:150;" 
data-frame_999="o:0;st:w;sR:7850;" 
data-frame_hover="c:#fff;bgc:#32b87b;bor:4px,4px,4px,4px;sp:200;e:power1.inOut;" 
style="z-index:6;background-color:#fff;font-family:DM Sans;"> 
    <!-- Do what you love, let our systems take care of  -->
    <a href="form_for_information.html" style="color:#1a1a1a"> Get Started! </a>
    <!-- Get Started! -->
</rs-layer>
```

Comment: Their documentation: https://www.sliderrevolution.com/faq/add-links-to-slides-and-layers/

Comment: I will be referring to their documentation from now on. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, if you put the "a" at the begining of the code, the link work in all seccion inside:

```
<a href="form_for_information.html" style="color:#1a1a1a">
<rs-layer id="slider-1-slide-1-layer-1" class="rev-btn" 
data-type="button" data-color="#251117" data-rsp_ch="on" 
data-xy="x:l,l,c,c;xo:92px,92px,0,92px;y:m;yo:150px,95px,150px,97px;" 
data-text="w:normal;s:17;l:60;fw:700;" data-dim="minh:0px,0px,none,0px;" 
data-padding="r:40;l:40;" data-border="bor:4px,4px,4px,4px;" 
data-frame_0="x:50,50,31,31;" 
data-frame_1="st:150;sp:1000;sR:150;" 
data-frame_999="o:0;st:w;sR:7850;" 
data-frame_hover="c:#fff;bgc:#32b87b;bor:4px,4px,4px,4px;sp:200;e:power1.inOut;" 
style="z-index:6;background-color:#fff;font-family:DM Sans;"> 
    <!-- Do what you love, let our systems take care of  -->
     Get Started! 
    <!-- Get Started! -->
</rs-layer></a>
```